# Update entity in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, hibernate, synchronization

I change user balance in database by using Hibernate and Spring Boot. For example, I have 1000 payments to different users and some payments could be to the same user more than 1 time.
I do it in different threads by using executor service.

PaymentService:

```
@Override
public void pay(BigDecimal amount) {
    List<Users> users = userRepository.findBySomeCriteria();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    
    users.forEach(u -> {
       executorService.execute(() -> walletService.add(u, amount, BalanceType.CASH));
       executorService.execute(() -> walletService.add(u, amount, BalanceType.TRADING));
    });
    executorService.shutDown();
}
```

WalletService:

```
@Override
public void add(User user, BigDecimal amount, Wallet.BalanceType balanceType) {
    ReentrantLock lock = locks.computeIfAbsent(LOCK_KEY + user.getId(), (key) -> new ReentrantLock());
    boolean isLock = lock.tryLock();
    while (!isLock) {
        isLock = lock.tryLock();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findByUser(user).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Wallet not found")
        );

        log.debug("[1] Cash balance: {}, trading balance: {}, add amount: {}", wallet.getCashBalance(), wallet.getTradingBalance(), amount);

        switch (balanceType) {
            case CASH -> wallet.setCashBalance(wallet.getCashBalance().add(amount));
            case TRADING -> wallet.setTradingBalance(wallet.getTradingBalance().add(amount));
            default -> throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Wrong balance type");

        }
        log.debug("[2] Cash balance: {}, trading balance: {}, add amount: {}", wallet.getCashBalance(), wallet.getTradingBalance(), amount);

        Wallet test = walletRepository.saveAndFlush(wallet);

        log.debug("[3] Cash balance: {}, trading balance: {}, add amount: {}", test.getCashBalance(), test.getTradingBalance(), amount);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The issue here is sometimes balance is not changing. Instead of `ReentrantLock` I tried `public synchronized void add`, but incorrect balance happened more often than with `ReentrantLock`.

With ReentrantLock the logs were:

```
10:00:00.925 [1] Cash balance: 0, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.925 [2] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.984 [3] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.996 [1] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, TRADING
10:00:00.996 [2] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 10, add amount: 10, TRADING
10:00:01.044 [3] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 10, add amount: 10, TRADING
```

- Expected: cash balance: 10, trading balance: 10
- Given: cash balance: 0, trading balance: 0

In logs all seems correct, but balance is not saved for some users.

With synchronized method and for each users 2 type of balance in 1 thread

```
executorService.execute(() -> {
       walletService.add(u, amount, BalanceType.TRADING));
       walletService.add(u, amount, BalanceType.TRADING));
    }
});
```

the logs were

```
10:00:00.100 [1] Cash balance: 0, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.100 [2] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.164 [3] Cash balance: 10, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, CASH
10:00:00.166 [1] Cash balance: 0, trading balance: 0, add amount: 10, TRADING
10:00:00.166 [2] Cash balance: 0, trading balance: 10, add amount: 10, TRADING
10:00:00.230 [3] Cash balance: 0, trading balance: 10, add amount: 10, TRADING
```

- Expected: cash balance: 10, trading balance: 10
- Given: cash balance: 0, trading balance: 10

In logs I see on the second call, I get the not updated balance from DB.

Why this issue could happen and how to guarantee a correct balance on changing it in multi-threading?

Comment: Is `locks` collection thread-safe?

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov yes, it is ```private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReentrantLock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();```

Comment: In this case, code looks correct. I only can advise you to check `PayService` is singleton, transactions are properly committed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, you trying to use the wrong approach, and your decision should not work by design. You should not handle concurrency on the application level - just let the database do it for you. In addition, it is useless to execute *walletService.add* in a different thread if you accrue lock and write to the database sequentially.

So just set the appropriate [optimistic](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking) or [pessimistic](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking) lock for your *wallet* entity and use it from different threads with no worry.

Also, keep in mind the interesting fact: the changes in the database are not fixed if you call the saveAndFlush method. The transaction is committed only if you leave the method annotated with @Transactional, so you should implement the intermediate layer of storage classes, annotate the storage layer class with @Transactional and call the wallet repository through this intermediate class.

Comment: Transactional annotation did not help. Should I use some specific propagation in the annotation? I'm going to implement the optimistic/pessimistic lock with retry, but I just wonder why this approach with concurrecny on the app level doesn't work, teoretically it should. And this issue happens only on 1 server with 24 core CPU, in another server with 4 core it is impossible to reproduce with the same code.

Comment: I did not find a way to hanlde it with concurrerncy on app level. Optimistic locking with ```@Retryable``` annotation solved the problem. Thanks